# How to generate pytest-html report in a dynamically created log directory

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

At present i am generating pytest html report to a predefined directory by providing this info in pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
addopts = -vra --html=./output/reports/report.html test.py
```

My html report is getting overwritten everytime i run test. Now i am dynamically creating an unique output folder for each run to keep my log save for future reference. I want my html report also to be part of this newly created directory. How in pytest I can redirect my html report to this directory.

I can code to move the newly created html report to this new directory, at the end of test run. But would be good if someone can suggest me a better way.

Comment: @hoefling thanks for your help. It solved my issue.